# any exchange to sell naked puts on bitcoin?

Tags: exchanges, trading, investing, options

I would like to sell puts on bitcoin to collect premiums if bitcoin goes up in value to usd, and to be long bitcoins at a lower price if I get exercised. This is much more predictable for me than just buying bitcoins at the top of a rally, given the volatile pricing in this market.

Does any active exchange have options on bitcoins? www.icbit.se has futures and options but doesn't seem to have any relevant products listed

Comment: Also possibly a duplicate of: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/4937/153

Comment: @StephenGornick also a possible duplicate of "why are you showing me obsolete questions with obsolete answers" :) but thanks I learned a little from those questions but 5 out of 6 of those exchanges are closed, or illiquid

Comment: Heh, sorry.  Yes, answers can get stale, but the question remains valid. You can upvote an answer if it suits you: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8528/153

Comment: A bounty on it might help?